# Get Data from internet and set the data in LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want get Data(with an api) from internet and set the data in LazyColumn
So I use this

```
@Composable
fun LazyColumn() {
    val list by remember { mutableStateOf(arrayListOf<HelloData>()) }
    Thread {
        for (index in 0..100) {
            list.add(HelloData(JSONObject(URL("https://ovooa.com/API/sjtx/api?form=%E5%A5%B3%E5%A4%B4").readText()).getString("text")))
        }
    }.start()


    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)) {
        items(list) { item ->
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(item.url, builder = {
                    crossfade(true)
                    diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                    memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                }),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

data class HelloData(val url: String)
```

It's not working.
I just want get the data from my api,then put them in an Image.
I can achieve it easily in traditional Android Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutableStateListOf` instead of `mutableStateOf`. mutableStateListOf detects changes to the list items whereas mutableStateOf will only detect changes to the list object.

Comment: Thanks very muck.
It's working